# How create a zend form object?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

In my Users controller I have an editAction. The below declaration is from editAction.

```
$form = $this->_getEditForm();//here I need to pass $user->email to the form class.
```

I have another class _gerEditForm() in same controller.

```
  private function _getEditForm()
   {
    $form = new Form_Admin_Users_Add(array(
            'method' => 'post',
            'action' => $this->_helper->url('edit', 'users'),

    ));
    return $form;
   }
enter code here
```

//form class

```
class Form_Admin_Users_Add extends Form_Abstract
{

    public function __construct($mail=null)
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->setName('user');
        //$userId = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('userId');
        //$userId->addFilter('Int');
        //$this->addElement($userId);

        $this->setAttrib('id', 'addUserForm');
        $this->setAttrib('class', 'formInline');

        $firstName = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('firstName');
        $firstName->setRequired(true)
        ->addFilter('StringTrim')
        ->addValidator('NotEmpty', false, array('messages'=>'First name cannot be empty'))
        ->addValidator('StringLength', false, array(1, 256))
        ->setLabel('First Name:');
        $this->addElement($firstName);

        $lastName = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('lastName');
        $lastName->setRequired(true)
        ->addFilter('StringTrim')
        ->addValidator('NotEmpty', false, array('messages'=>'Last name cannot be empty'))
        ->addValidator('StringLength', false, array(1, 256))
        ->setLabel('Last Name:');
        $this->addElement($lastName);

        $email = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('email');
        $email->setLabel('Email :')
        ->addValidator('NotEmpty', false, array('messages'=>'email cannot be empty'))
        ->addFilter('StripTags')
        ->addFilter('StringTrim')
        ->addValidator('EmailAddress')
        ->addValidator(new BusinessForum_Validate_UniqueEmail($mail));
```

Now I need to pass the email the form class. But I don't know how to do this.
Please help me in this regard.
Thanks

Comment: Did you make the form class at `forms/Admin/Users/Add.php`? Show us that code.

Comment: Yes, I did. Now I have attached the code with the post

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a bit confused. The `__construct` function takes one argument, `$mail`. You're passing that to your `BusinessForum_Validate_UniqueEmail` class.

But in your `_getEditForm` function, you're passing in an array to that `$mail` argument that looks like it has settings for the form, not email information.

If that's just how you named stuff, and that's how it works, fine. Then you should just need to add a second parameter to your `__construct` function:

```
public function __construct($mail=null, $emailAddress="")
```

Pass it in from your `_getEditForm` function:

```
private function _getEditForm($emailAddress="")
{
    $form = new Form_Admin_Users_Add(array(
        'method' => 'post',
        'action' => $this->_helper->url('edit', 'users')
    ), $emailAddress);
    return $form;
}
```

And pass the email address to your `_getEditForm` function:

```
$form = $this->_getEditForm($user->email);
```